# Adding new row with calculative field in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I am facing problem adding a new row with calculative field in ng-grid.

Html Code..

```
<div class="costsheetGrid" ng-controller="costsheetGridController">
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="addAnotherRow()" href="javascript:void(0);">Add Another Row</a>
        </p>
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript Code..

```
$scope.gridData = [
            {
                'Consumption': '100',
                'ConversionQuantity': '3',
            }
        ];

angular.forEach($scope.gridData, function (row) {
                row.getActualConsumption = function () {
                    return row.Consumption / row.ConversionQuantity;
                };
            });

$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'gridData',
            enableCellSelection: true,
            enableRowSelection: false,
            enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
            columnDefs: [

            { field: "Consumption", displayName: "Consumption", width: 100 },

            { field: "ConversionQuantity", displayName: "Conversion Quantity", width: 120 },
            { field: "getActualConsumption()", displayName: "Actual Consumption", width: 120, enableCellEdit: false }
        ]
        };

$scope.addAnotherRow = function () {
            $scope.gridData.push({
                'Consumption': '',
                'ConversionQuantity': '',
            });
        };
```

This code works perfectly when i change Consumption or ConversionQuantity in first row of grid and it calculates the Actual Consumption. When i click the "Add Another Row" button it adds a new row but when i insert Consumption or ConversionQuantity in second row then it cant calculate the Actual Consumption.

So, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only attaching the `getActualConsumption` function for each row on the initial data. When creating a new row, you should also add that function.

```
$scope.addAnotherRow = function () {
            $scope.gridData.push({
                'Consumption': '',
                'ConversionQuantity': '',
                 getActualConsumption: function () {
                    return this.Consumption / this.ConversionQuantity;
                }
            });
        };
```

**Please note** that I've just copied your implementation of `getActualConsumption` - you should probably be doing some sort of validation to ensure you don't get errors by diving by zero and ensuring that both the values are actual numbers